# what could be the best practices to allow user signup and login for a application using IOTA as a base?

Tags: iota-network

- Method for signup and login should not be cumbersome; ie: simple as normal methods of username/password or facebook and google oauth.
- Should not be cumbersome to request user to input seed to login :P

user 1 (credentials)-> seed unique (ABS9...) -> address (SSDBS9...) -> Do the transaction

user 2(credentials) -> seed unique (RBS9...) -> address (TREBS9...) -> Do the transaction

Comment: Could you specify the location of the application? Is it a website or a Wallet? What's the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

**Your server or somebody else should never ever have access to the unencrypted seed, if not needed.**
You could connect your app with a centralized server and store a *securely encrypted* seed-file there.

1. User visits your website / app
2. User sees "Connect with Dropbox / Google Drive"
3. User Login with OAuth @ Dropbox / Google Drive
4. User sets a secure password at your application
5. Generate a new seed (cryptographically secure)
6. Encrypt the seed with the password (see *key derivation functions* / *AES*)
7. Encrypted seed is stored at Dropbox / Google Drive

When you want to store the *securely encrypted* seed on your own server, you could use *Secure Remote Password protocol* (SRP) for the authentication. This way you could use the same password for authentication and encryption.